# how to get a single result from a voice recognizer with out "["and "]" in the start and the end of result

Tags: android

i am using voice recognizer in my app. but i want a single result from the voice recognizer **without** the **"["** and **"]"** in the beginning and the end of the result provided by the voice recognizer.

at present i have a code which gives me a single result but it give "[" and "]" in the front and in the end of the result which i obtain.

please check my code make the possible correction and modifications and give a appropiate answer i am very new to android.

code : **MainActivity.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int RECOGNIZER_EXAMPLE = 1001;
private TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_result);

    //set up button listner 

    Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trigger);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = 
                    new Intent (RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,   RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"SAY A WORD OR PHRASE\nAND IT WILL BE SHOWN AS TEXT");
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
            startActivityForResult(intent,RECOGNIZER_EXAMPLE);

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //use a switch statament for more than one request code check

    if(requestCode==RECOGNIZER_EXAMPLE && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        //RETURNED DATA IS A LIST OF MATCHES TO THE SPEECH IPUT
        ArrayList<String> result = 
            data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        tv.setText(result.toString());
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

Comment: get first element in your result list , tv.setText(result.get(0).toString());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int RECOGNIZER_EXAMPLE = 1001;
private TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_result);

//set up button listner 

Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trigger);
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = 
                new Intent (RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,   RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"SAY A WORD OR PHRASE\nAND IT WILL BE SHOWN AS TEXT");
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
        startActivityForResult(intent,RECOGNIZER_EXAMPLE);

    }
});

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
//use a switch statament for more than one request code check

if(requestCode==RECOGNIZER_EXAMPLE && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
    //RETURNED DATA IS A LIST OF MATCHES TO THE SPEECH IPUT
    ArrayList<String> result = 
        data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
     tv.setText(result.get(0).toString());
}

super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //use a switch statament for more than one request code check

    if(requestCode==RECOGNIZER_EXAMPLE && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        //RETURNED DATA IS A LIST OF MATCHES TO THE SPEECH IPUT
        ArrayList<String> result = 
            data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        // result here is array list , we need any element to be viewed in textview
        tv.setText(result.get(0).toString());
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

So the change we made

```
tv.setText(result.toString());
```

To

```
tv.setText(result.get(0).toString());
```